# CakePHP - Redirect to controller without action and without slug

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, routes

Using CakePHP, I would like to redirect from this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/songs/12345/Michael-Jackson-Billie-Jean
```

to this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/songs/12345
```

In the new URL, the controller is `songs`, the id is `12345`, the implied action is `view`, and the slug (`Michael-Jackson-Billie-Jean`) is removed.

Is it possible to program this redirect using the routes config file, or will I need to program a slightly more advanced redirect in either a controller or route class?

I have tried the following two possibilities to no avail.  In this first attempt, I end up getting a URL with `view` in the URL and parameters appended to the end of the URL:

```
Router::redirect(
    '/songs/:id/**',
    array('controller' => 'songs', 'action' => 'view'),
    array('persist' => array('id'))
);
// Redirects to http://www.example.com/songs/view/Michael-Jackson-Billie-Jean%2Fid%3A1286072880/id:view
```

In my second attempt, the redirect almost works, but the string `:id` is literally echoed in the URL:

```
Router::redirect(
    '/songs/:id/**',
    '/songs/:id'
);
// Redirects to http://www.example.com/songs/:id
```

I suppose I could write this redirect in the root .htaccess file, but I would prefer to keep all the routing in one place; namely, the CakePHP routes file.

Does anyone know how I can redirect to `http://www.example.com/songs/:id` where `:id` is the song ID and not literally the string `:id`?  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Use below route for the simple solution:

`Router::connect('/songs/*', array('controller' => 'songs', 'action' => 'view'),array('pass' => array('id')));`

```
function view($id=null){   

         // $id will be song id
         // For example, http://www.example.com/songs/12345 here $id is 12345

}
```

Do not use .htaccess, it will be handled easily from routes.php.

Cheers

Comment: -1 This answer does not redirect whatsoever and completely ignores the slug.